# How do you put a label underneath a set of inputs that are inline (CSS)?

Tags: html, css

I have my html set up like so ([..] is an input field). I'm also using Foundation 5.

[..][..][..][..][..][..][..][..]

and I want to number each input, with the number being right below (or above) each input field. The css for the input fields is

```
    .gant{
        display: inline !important;
        width:40px !important;
        margin:auto !important;
        background-color:white !important;
    }
```

I've checked online pretty thoroughly, but every recommendation I've come across seems to push each input field onto a separate line.

If thats not descriptive enough I can put the html online and link to it.

Comment: You can add an image shwing ur required output for better understanding.

Comment: Yes, please add it to fiddle and show an image for desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would wrap the inputs within another tag and inline-block that tag, something like this http://codepen.io/leopic/pen/korwz 
[image]

Comment: great! glad I could help, please be sure to mark my solution as the accepted answer if you indeed used it

Answer (score 0):

I can see two options basically - wrapping each `<input>` in another element, or having a list of all the inputs, followed by a second list of all the numbers (which semantically isn't fantastic.

I've put together an example of using an `<ol>` with styling to put the number below each field. I think semantically this is a good option, as if you want them numbered it is indeed an ordered list.

Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/bL5qy/ and let me know if that's the kind of thing you're wanting.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need something to wrap the input fields, and an element around the label part. For something like this:

```
<div class="wrapper"><label for="input1">1</label><input id="input1"/></div>
```

This CSS should do what you want

```
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.5ex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the most simple way :) no other elements are required. Also, you should avoid using `!important` declarations as much as possible, they will make your CSS harder to maintain.

Have a fiddle - [Fiddle Link!](http://jsfiddle.net/LvvyY/)

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="one" />
<input type="text" id="two" />
<input type="text" id="three" />
<input type="text" id="four" />
<input type="text" id="five" />

<label for="one" class="clear">1</label>
<label for="two">2</label>
<label for="three">3</label>
<label for="four">4</label>
<label for="five">5</label>
```

CSS

```
input {
    width: 20px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
label {
    width: 20px;
    margin: 0 4px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
.clear { clear: left; }
```